# Avoid duplicate CRON entry creation by a particular script

Tags: bash, shell, cron

Below shell function creates a CRON entry programatically.

```
function create_cron(){
    echo ""
    echo "Create CRON entry"
    #write out current crontab
    crontab -l > allcrons
    #echo new cron into cron file
    echo "0 1 * * * python /opt/EO/Ava/utils/xtr_test_aggregation.py" >> allcrons
    display_all_crons allcrons
    #install new cron file
    crontab allcrons
    rm allcrons
}
```

The only issue with the above function is of the possibility of duplicate CRON entry creation, if the script is run twice. I had like to create a CRON job only if it is not present. Please note that if there are duplicate entries already present, I had like to leave them there. I am only bothered about the duplicate entries created specifically by this script.

Comment: then grep the crontab for that exact line, and don't add it if the grep returns results.

Comment: You can make the grepping easier and more robust by appending a something like `# XTR_TEST_ENTRY` to the command. You can then easily recognize the entry even if the time has been changed or the admin replaced `python` with `python2.7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into crontab and check if the your entry already exists, if it doesn't only then you add it:

```
function create_cron(){
    echo ""
    echo "Create CRON entry"
    new_entry="0 1 * * * python /opt/EO/Ava/utils/xtr_test_aggregation.py"
    if ! crontab -l | fgrep -q "$new_entry"; then
        #write out current crontab
        crontab -l > allcrons
        #echo new cron into cron file
        echo "$new_entry" >> allcrons
        display_all_crons allcrons
        #install new cron file
        crontab allcrons
        rm allcrons
    fi
}
```